# Angular2: update table view after retrieving data

Tags: angular, html-table

I have a simple table like

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped ">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Benutzer</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Nachname</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let empl of employers">
        <td>{{empl.name}}</td>
        <td>{{empl.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{empl.lastName}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

to display data. While it is first displayed I fetch data for `employers` with a `Promise` which takes quite some time. The display works quite well with empty data.

My problem starts when I encapsulate the whole table with something like

```
<div class="panel-heading">{{title}}</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  .... table ....
</div>
```

This paints a border around the table - which is OK as long as no data is included. But when I have data which has *loooooooooooooooong* content the table stretches - and the border is not redrawn/refreshed.

How to achieve that the border of `panel-body` is evaluted again *after*  `*ngFor` has finished?

Comment: You can use `*ngIf="employers"` which can help you in case to load the area when if condition is true

Comment: I think it's important to know what CSS attributes the table and the panel-body have (mainly 'display' and 'overflow'). Does the table overflow the panel-body element after displaying the data?

Comment: @JánHalaša: To your q: yes, the table exceeds the panel-body size after displaying. As well as when there is not enough space and I shrink the window the border shrinks much more than the table itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is more about CSS than Angular. If you have a long TABLE element in a DIV element with a fixed width, then the table will overflow the div (get wider).

To get around it, you can either set "overflow: auto" on the div or limit the length of the table cells (by setting "table-layout: fixed", setting its width and wrapping contents of its cells in DIVs with overflow: hidden). Or you can use some responsive structure instead of the TABLE. Such as a flex layout.

Comment: Thx! the `style="overflow: auto"` fixed this issue!